# How to do SQL inner queries through SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, inner-query

Lets say I have two tables:

- ticket with columns [id,date, userid] userid is a foreign key that
  references user.id
- user with columns [id,name]

And I wish to perform the following query through sqlalchemy:

```
select ticket.id, user.name 
from
 (
   select * from ticket
   where ticket.date >= '2015-05-18'
 ) as ticket 
left join user on ticket.user_id=user.id
```

I am not quite sure how to perform inner queries through sqlalchemy. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can provide a `query` as the target for another `query`'s `.join` methods, as shown here: < http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries >. So first build the interior query, stored as a variable, then utilize it within a join. Alternatively, you can move the `where` clause outside, thereby removing the need for a subquery at all: `select t.id, u.name from ticket t left join user u on t.user_id = u.id where t.date >= '2015-05-18'`

Comment: If you really wanted you could put that whole thing in text to query. so something like `results=session.execute(text(<query string>))`